# Как программно изменить Button margin

Tags: android, android-view

Есть кнопка у которой установлен layout_marginRight. Я хочу в коде при выполнении определенного условия изменить фон и layout_marginRight, с фоном получается, а с маржином - нет, как это можно реализовать?

activity.java

```
    private void reRenderButton(boolean finish) {
    if (finish){
        mButtonNext.setText("ЗАВЕРШИТЬ");
        mButtonNext.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_next_word_finish_rectangle));
        mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LearnActivity.this, CheckKnowledgeActivity.class));
            }
        });
    }else {
        mButtonNext.setText("СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЛОВО");
        mButtonNext.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_next_word_rectangle));
        mButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem() + 1);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/colorBackgroundGrey"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/header_button_shape_baground"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/button_next_height"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/default_marginRight"
        android:background="@drawable/button_next_word_rectangle"
        android:text="СЛЕДУЮЩЕЕ СЛОВО"
        android:textSize="@dimen/button_next_font_size"
        android:textColor="@color/colorFontBlue"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться `LayoutParams` с параметрами `LinearLayout`. Например:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
layoutParams.setMarginEnd(12);
```

Урок по этой теме: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YOm60DFLPeA&index=18&list=PLyfVjOYzujugap6Rf3ETNKkx4v9ePllNK